# CSS three layer div

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
#Parent {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color:#cccdce;
  width:70%;
  height:500px;
  float:left;
}

#child {
  padding:15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}

 <div id="Parent">
   <div id="child">
     <div>aaaa</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I now have is:

[image]

I want to know why padding is not working? Isn't padding is supposed to set the space between parent and child element? Why it is not working and overlapping?

I want to do this:

[image]

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmwrQY

Comment: Oh nice, it is what I want

Comment: great. yeah you just applied padding to the wrong element. "Isn't padding is supposed to set the space between parent and child element?" - it will if you apply padding to the parent, but you applied it to the child.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flexbox and remove `floats`, and FYI your `padding` needed to be set in parent not child

```css
#Parent {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #cccdce;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  display:flex;
  padding: 15px;
}

#child {
  padding: inherit;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <div id="child">
    aaaa
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `padding` to the parent and remove the `floats`. This will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you give padding to the right element. Right now you are assigning 15px padding to the child. That's the reason why there is 15px space between the text and the child. If you add a padding to the parent-id, you create "space between parent and child element":

```css
#Parent {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```css
#Parent {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#child {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 470px;
}

#grand {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grand">aaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```